# top 10 results in solr using java, spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, solr, spring-data-solr

I am using java in spring MVC framework for querying, my query is showing 600+ results but I only want the top 10 results.

This is what I have so far:

```
 public interface ProductRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Product, String>{

    @Query("Product_Name:?0")
    public List<Product> findByProductName(String productName);


 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Product, String>{

@Query("Product_Name:?0")
public List<Product> findByProductName(String productName, Pageable pageable); }
```

Then, call it like this:

```
    PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, 10);
    myRepository.findByProductName("Product Name", pageRequest);
```

References:

Spring data - [Special Parameters Handling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.6.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#repositories.special-parameters)

Spring Data - [Page Request API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.6.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html)